# Unwanted Space in iOS 17 Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swiftui, navigation

I'm encountering an issue with the navigation bar on iOS 17 mobile devices. There's unwanted space appearing, which is not expected behavior.
This issue is specific to iOS 17; it does not occur on other iOS versions.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUQql.png]

I've also tested it on multiple iOS 17 devices to confirm that the issue is consistent.

Comment: Can you share your code? do you want to completely remove the Navigation bar?

Comment: Show the minimal code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution i found was that instead of using **NavigationView** replace it with **NavigationStack**. The downside of this is that NavigationStack is only available for iOS 16 and up.

OR

*Wrap everything in a VStack*